# How do I cross-compile for ARM and debug on another machine in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, embedded, cross-platform, gdbserver

I am trying to set up a NetBeans x86_64 environment where I can write code and add breakpoints in the IDE, cross-compile for ARM, then run the binary on a raspberry pi (for now) running gdbserver.

A common option is to use a remote build host to build, run, and debug the binary, but I will eventually be working on an embedded device that will not have room for a development toolchain. I am using a pi right now to learn how I will compile and debug once the embedded machines arrive. **Please do not suggest using a remote build host.**

Right now, my best guess has been to replace the run command with `./run.sh "${OUTPUT_PATH}"`, where run.sh is a small bash script that transfers the newly compiled binary to the pi, then runs `gdbserver --debug localhost:6000 ~/app`. There is [a gdbserver plugin for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37426/gdbserver) that I have been able to attach to, after NetBeans has transferred the binary and run gdbserver, but all that gives me is the stdout of gdb (which makes sense). What I want is setting and stepping through breakpoints using the IDE and watching variables change, but I can't seem to get that to work using this setup.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I've been programming embedded systems for a long time now, and the toolchains do not take up room on the embedded system.  I recommend using a JTAG debugger, provided your embedded system supports the interfaced.  There are many JTAG debuggers that make debugging a "remote" system very easy.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews jtag debuggers are primarily for debugging bare metal programs and kernels; this question appears to be about debugging a userspace program running under an operating system, which is normally done with tools like the proposed gdbserver.

Comment: "NetBeans isn't behaving how I would expect." questions here need to state the *specific* problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for pointing that out, I edited for clarity

Comment: Sounds like this plugin isn't what you want.  What you need to accomplish is pointing Netbeans at the local `gdb` just as if you were going to debug locally, but then the Netbeans debugger interface code or configuration must issue the `target remote host:port` command to `gdb` (I often did this by invoking `gdb` with the commandline option to run a script of commands before going interactive).  The debugger interface must also beware of certain differences, for example a remote can `cont` but not `run`.

Answer (score 0):

> gdbserver --debug localhost:6000 ~/app

This doesn't match the invocation syntax documented for versions of `gdbserver` I'm familiar with, but even without knowing the form, the argument seems mistaken.

**"localhost"** always refers to the *same* computer, never another.  So specifying "localhost" would imply you were going to run `gdbserver` and `gdb` on the same machine, which negates the whole point of using `gdbserver`.

It's unclear what your command causes `gdbserver` to do, but neither possibility is good.

- if it causes `gdbserver` to *listen* on the loopback interface rather than INADDR_ANY, then only programs running on the target itself will be able to contact the `gdbserver` process, which rules out the remote gdb.
- if it causes `gdbserver` to attempt to *connect* to an already running remote `gdb`, then that won't work either, as it will be attempting to connect to a non-existent *local* one.

Likely what you want to do is something like

```
target> gdbserver :6000 ~/app

devmachine>gdb build/app
gdb> target remote target_machine_ip:6000
```

Comment: Setting the host to localhost does not restrict access to only the loopback interface. I am able to connect from the NetBeans machine using `gdb> target remote 169.254.174.111:6000`. An example of someone using gdbserver similar to how I am using it [can be found here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example/)

Comment: @Drew - the erroneous specification of localhost for the listen end of a remote connection may be *ignored* by `gdbserver`, but it's still *erroneous* as it would cause a problem if not ignored.  A typical gdbserver "comm" argument (as the ordinary manpage calls it) doesn't have a host, just a colon and a port.